# How to manage the 'is null' and 'is not null' filter in serverside using kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI in which I have data filters like 'is greater than', 'is less than', 'is greater than or equal', 'null' and 'is not null'.

All are working but when I select the 'null' or 'is not null' filter, they throw an exception.

I have used the following piece of code to filter:

```
var entityType = (typeof(T));
PropertyInfo property;
if (filter.Field.Contains("."))
    property = GetNestedProp<T>(filter.Field);
else
    property = entityType.GetProperty(filter.Field, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    property = entityType.GetRuntimeProperty(filter.Field);
    var parameterIndex = parameters.Count;
    switch (filter.Operator.ToLower())
    {
        case "eq":
        case "neq":
        case "gte":
        case "gt":
        case "lte":
        case "lt":
        case "isnull":
        case "isnotnull":
            if (property != null)
            {
                if (typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    //if(filter.Operator.ToLower()== "isnull") // check to the all instead of giving values to the  case 
                    parameters.Add(DateTime.Parse(filter.Value).Date);
                    return string.Format("EntityFunctions.TruncateTime({0}){1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                }
                if (typeof(DateTime?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    parameters.Add(DateTime.Parse(filter.Value).Date);
                    return string.Format("EntityFunctions.TruncateTime({0}){1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                }
                if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    parameters.Add(int.Parse(filter.Value));
                    return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                }
                if (typeof(int?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    parameters.Add(int.Parse(filter.Value));
                    return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                }
                if (typeof(Decimal?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    if (filter.Operator.ToLower() == "isnull")
                    {
                       parameters.Add(Boolean.Parse(filter.Value));
                        return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parameters.Add(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value));
                        return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }
                }
                if (typeof(Decimal).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    parameters.Add(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value));
                    return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                }
                //if(typeof(Boolean?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                //{
                //    parameters.Add(Boolean.Parse(filter.Value));
                //}

                //if (typeof(Boolean).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                //{
                //    parameters.Add(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value));
                //}
            }
            parameters.Add(filter.Value);
            return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
        case "startswith": parameters.Add(filter.Value); return string.Format("{0}.StartsWith(" + "@{1})", filter.Field, index);
        case "endswith":
            parameters.Add(filter.Value); return string.Format("{0}.EndsWith(" + "@{1})", filter.Field, index);
        case "contains": parameters.Add(filter.Value); return string.Format("{0}.Contains(" + "@{1})", filter.Field, index);
        default: throw new ArgumentException("This operator is not yet supported for this Grid", filter.Operator);
    }
}
```